# OSError: libcufft.so.11 and OSError: libnvJitLink.so.12 In colab

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, text-to-speech

While reading and following along, I ran into a problem and asked a question. The method is to create a data folder in colab and upload the files where I recorded my voice into the filelists.zip folder and then learn. An oserror occurred while I was following the reply that fixed the existing error code. How can I solve this?
https://sce-tts.github.io/#/v2/train

```
/content/TTS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch-2.1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/torch/__init__.py", line 174, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libcufft.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TTS/bin/train_glow_tts.py", line 10, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch-2.1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/torch/__init__.py", line 234, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch-2.1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/torch/__init__.py", line 195, in _load_global_deps
    _preload_cuda_deps(lib_folder, lib_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch-2.1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/torch/__init__.py", line 161, in _preload_cuda_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libnvJitLink.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```